# HTTP Client Skeleton

Tags: c++, object-oriented, http

I've made a simple winhttp client in C++ and here is kind've the skeleton of the header file. I was thinking of initializing the session once and then using it throughout the rest of my http client structure. I don't know if this is super stupid but this was my thinking. This is just a skeleton of what I would like it to be and wanted to get a feel if this skeleton of a http client could be improved. Another question I have is:
"If I create multiple connections using WinHTTPConnect is that a bad idea and could their be issues, if so should I do something similar to how I have my session?"

```cpp
#ifndef HTTPLITE_H
#define HTTPLITE_H
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Winhttp.h>
//everything required in terms of imports and libraries
#pragma comment(lib, "winhttp.lib")

class httplite {
private:
    //creates our local session within our class
    HINTERNET sess = WinHttpOpen(NULL,
        WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_AUTOMATIC_PROXY,
        WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME,
        WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS,
        NULL
    );
public:
    httplite();
    ~httplite();
    
    LPCWSTR get(
        LPWSTR host,
        LPWSTR path=NULL,
        LPWSTR headers=NULL,
        boolean https=false
    );
    
    LPCSTR post(
        LPWSTR host,
        LPWSTR path=NULL,
        LPCSTR content= NULL,
        LPWSTR headers= NULL,
        boolean https=false
    );
};
#endif HTTPLITE_H
```

Comment: url consists of a few more fields: `schema/user/password/host/port/path/query/fragment` you should be able to handle all this in your `get` and `post` commands. user/password are rare. schema defines default port. host can by IP/domainName. query can support multiple of the same value.

Comment: @MartinYork thats a good point, I'll implement that. Otherwise does my class structure look fine? Do you think that I could run maybe 50-100 threads and not have issues?

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review site where we review actual working code from your project and provide suggestions on how to improve that code. The question indicates that this is not the actual code of the project and that makes the question off-topic for this site. If you want a good answer rather than a short answer in a comment please post the actual header file and possibly the .cpp file that implements the code.

Comment: @WindowsGoBRRRRRR Not really much to review here. HTTP and REST also allow for a couple of other commands. `PUT` and `DELETE` are relatively common. But you can find a full list here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods

Comment: @WindowsGoBRRRRRR I think adding `https` in this interface is the wrong thing to do. That is the next layer up. I would have `httplite` interface (that takes a URL) then have an `httpslite` interface that accepts an `httplite` as a member for the constructor and then wraps all the read/write calls so the correct encryption can be done before passing to the `httplite` interface for actual transport.